# Find the image matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For a linear image F: R3 → R3 it applies that

F(1,0,0) = (1,0,1) and F(1,0,1) = (2,1,0).

Furthermore, the vector u = (1,1, −1) is an eigenvector with the eigenvalue 2.
Determine the imaging matrix for F in standard basis.

I can think of it as you take the input (1,0,0) and spite out the output (1,0,1)
and take in the input (1,0,1) and spite out the output (2,1,0).

I know the standard basis in Linear Algebra is (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1) but i can't understand how to apply on this problem here to find the image matrix ??

Comment: Hint: $F(1,0,0)+F(0,0,1)=F(1,0,1)$ and $F(1,1,-1)=F(1,0,0)+F(0,1,0)-F(0,0,1)$

Comment: @JMoravitz Why F(1,0,0)+F(0,0,1)=F(1,0,1)  where does the equation comes from?

Comment: Because $F$ is linear.  Recall... a linear function applied to the sum of two inputs is equal to the sum of the linear function applied to each input individually... that is to say $F(a+b)=F(a)+F(b)$.  Here... we have $a=(1,0,0)$ and $b=(0,0,1)$ and $a+b=(1,0,1)$

Comment: Similarly, a linear function applied to a multiple of an input is equal to the multiple of the linear function applied to the input itself... that is to say $F(\alpha v) = \alpha F(v)$... So for instance $F((0,0,-1)) = F(-1(0,0,1)) = -1 \cdot F((0,0,1))$.  These are basic properties of linear functions which should be second nature and are at the core of everything that goes on in a course on linear algebra.

Comment: Okay i have F(1,0,0) = (1,0,1) in the linear function and that is one standardbasis?

Comment: That last comment makes no sense and makes me suspect that you don't know what is meant by the terminology used.

Comment: Can i replace the input of the standard matrix with the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a\\d\\g\end{bmatrix}$$

That is to say... if we want to figure out the corresponding matrix for $F$... and we know what $F(1,0,0)$ is... that result is precisely the first column of the matrix representation of $F$.

We are told that $F(1,0,0)=(1,0,1)$ so... we can fill out the first column of the matrix representation of $F$

> $\begin{bmatrix}1&.&.\\0&.&.\\1&.&.\end{bmatrix}$

Similarly, if we were to figure out $F(0,1,0)$ we would know the second column of $F$ and similarly $F(0,0,1)$ would tell us the third column of $F$.

To find these, use the facts given in the problem and that $F$ is linear.

So, since $F(0,0,1)=F(1,0,1)-F(1,0,0)$ we have

> $F(0,0,1) = (2,1,0)-(1,0,1) = (1,1,-1)$ and so we can fill in the third column, giving our work so far as being $\begin{bmatrix}1&.&1\\0&.&1\\1&.&-1\end{bmatrix}$ with the middle column still needing to be figured out.

For this last part, we use the definition of what it means to be an eigenvalue-eigenvector pair to learn that

$F(1,1,-1)=2\cdot (1,1,-1)=(2,2,-2)$

We also use what we know of $F$ being linear to know that

$F(0,1,0)=F(1,1,-1)-F(1,0,0)+F(0,0,1)$

from which we can then perform the necessary arithmetic to find the value of $F(0,1,0)$ and use that result as the second column of $F$'s matrix representation to complete the problem.

Comment: Last Vector (0,1,0) which equations do you use there?

Comment: @john I told you in my last several lines already.  I just left the final arithmetic for you to do.

Comment: Oh okay it is Av = eigenvalue* v